# how to open the key board inside layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-keypad

i need to open the keyboard inside my `layout` where i have an `edittextbox` see the image below

[image]

in this image

`pink`-`header` and `footer`

`brown`-`edittext`

`blue`-whole `layout`

`red`-`keyboard`

anyone help me to solve this. help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no option in android to set the position of the softkeyboar. you can make your own keyboard in you xml.

Comment: @Musdassar i have my own keyboard but how can open inside that `layout` i dont know have any links send to me

Comment: you make your keyboard in xml or it's a keyboard class?

Comment: do you make your keyboard in xml or it's a keyboard class?

Comment: @Musdassar keybord class.i did't create xml

Comment: we are close to solution. is your keyboard class is extended from KeyboardView?

Comment: i think you can use your custom class in xml like this
 <yourPackagename.CustomeKeyboard
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

Comment: @Musdassar ya its size reduced but i cant able to open inside my layout it hides my footer

Comment: make your parent layout "RelativeLayout" then set the keyboar view to above "footer" andr below "editText"

Comment: @Musadassar i had created keyboard separate so i cant able to this i think.